# Aceptar acentos y ñ en stdin.readLineSync() en dart

Tags: flutter, dart, stdin

Cuando leo palabras de la consola que tenga acentos o ñ me las quita, ejemplo:
si escribo "reñí" y luego lo imprimo, escribe "re". ¿Cómo puedo resolver esto?

**Este es mi código:**

```dart
  _palabra = stdin.readLineSync()!;
  print(_palabra);
```

**Salida:**
diñé
di

Comment: Hola, pásate por el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) y lee el artículo de [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), después edita tu pregunta o de lo contrario la cerrarán.

Comment: Parece ser un problema que solo pasa en [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69823403/8838721).